# I want to implement a pre-defined formula with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, formula

I have a formula that I want to implement in JavaScript and 5 input fields.

Here is the HTML code: (sorry for the language, it is locale)

```
<div class="row" style="padding:10px 12px;">
                  <div class="row">          
                    <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                      <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="K">Shkolla e Mesme:</label>
                      <div class="controls">
                        <select name="K" class="span3 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-control1" id="K">
                          <option value="0">Zgjidh Shkollën e Mesme</option>
                          <option value="0" disabled="">---------------------------------------------------------</option>
                          <option value="1">GJIMNAZ</option><option value="2">GJIMNAZ ME KOHË TË SHKURTUAR</option><option value="3">SEKSION DY GJUHËSH SHQIP-FRËNGJISHT</option><option value="4">SEKSION DY GJUHËSH SHQIP-ITALISHT</option><option value="5">SEKSION DY GJUHËSH SHQIP-GJERMANISHT</option><option value="6">GJIMNAZ GJUHËSOR</option><option value="7">SHKOLLË ARTISTIKE/KOREOGRAFIKE</option><option value="8">SHKOLLË SPORTIVE</option><option value="9">SHKOLLË PEDAGOGJIKE</option><option value="10">HOTELERI-TURIZËM</option><option value="11">SHËRBIME MJETESH TRANSPORTI</option><option value="12">MEKANIKË</option><option value="13">ELEKTROTEKNIKË</option><option value="14">ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="15">PËRPUNIM DRURI</option><option value="16">NDËRTIM</option><option value="17">TEKSTIL-KONFEKSIONE</option><option value="18">TEKNOLOGJI USHQIMORE</option><option value="19">BUJQËSI</option><option value="20">SHËRBIME SOCIALE DHE SHËNDETSORE</option><option value="21">VETERINARI</option><option value="22">GJEODEZI</option><option value="23">INSTALUES I SISTEMEVE TERMOHIDRAULIKE </option><option value="24">LLOGARI</option><option value="25">SHËRBIME BANKARE</option><option value="26">ADMINSITRIM BIZNESI </option><option value="27">RRJETE TË DHËNASH</option><option value="28">MBËSHTETJE E PËRDORUESVE TË TIK</option><option value="29">ELEKTRONIK NË TEKNOLOGJINË E AUTOMATIZIMIT </option><option value="30">SILVIKULTURË</option><option value="31">HARRY FULTZ, BIZNES</option><option value="32">HARRY FULTZ, ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="33">HARRY FULTZ, AUTOMEKANIK</option><option value="34">PETER MAHRINGER TEKNOLOGJI INFORMACIONI</option><option value="35">PROFILI IM S'ËSHTË NË LISTË</option><option value="36">SHKOLLË PEDAGOGJIKE (TIK)</option>            </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>



                      <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="M">Field1:</label>
                          <div class="controls"><input name="M" id="M" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota mesatare e shkolles se mesme"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="D1">Field2:</label>
                          <div class="controls"><input name="D1" id="D1" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota e provimit me detyrim 1"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="D2">Field3:</label>
                          <div class="controls"><input name="D2" id="D2" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota e provimit me detyrim 2"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="D3">Field4:</label>
                          <div class="controls"><input name="D3" id="D3" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota e provimit me detyrim 2"></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; fflex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="Z1">Field5:</label>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="row">
                       <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                        <select name="Z1" class="span2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-control1" id="Z1">
                          <option value="0">Zgjidh Lëndën</option>
                          <option value="0" disabled="">---------------------------------------------------------</option>
                          <option value="42">ADMINSITRIM BIZNESI </option><option value="51">Anglisht</option><option value="58">Anglisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="9">Biologji bërthamë</option><option value="10">Biologji e thelluar</option><option value="35">BUJQËSI</option><option value="15">Ekonomi bërthamë</option><option value="16">Ekonomi e thelluar</option><option value="45">ELEKTRONIK NË TEKNOLOGJINË E AUTOMATIZIMIT </option><option value="30">ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="29">ELEKTROTEKNIKË</option><option value="21">Filozofi</option><option value="7">Fizikë bërthamë</option><option value="8">Fizikë e thelluar</option><option value="53">Frëngjisht</option><option value="60">Frengjisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="38">GJEODEZI</option><option value="13">Gjeografi bërthamë</option><option value="14">Gjeografi e thelluar</option><option value="54">Gjermanisht</option><option value="61">Gjermanisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="56">Greqisht</option><option value="63">Greqisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="49">HARRY FULTZ, AUTOMEKANIK</option><option value="47">HARRY FULTZ, BIZNES</option><option value="48">HARRY FULTZ, ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="24">Histori arti</option><option value="25">Histori baleti</option><option value="11">Histori bërthamë</option><option value="12">Histori e thelluar</option><option value="23">Histori muzike</option><option value="26">HOTELERI-TURIZËM</option><option value="39">INSTALUES I SISTEMEVE TERMOHIDRAULIKE </option><option value="52">Italisht</option><option value="59">Italisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="5">Kimi bërthamë</option><option value="6">Kimi e thelluar</option><option value="3">Letërsi e thelluar</option><option value="40">LLOGARI</option><option value="4">Matematikë e thelluar</option><option value="44">MBËSHTETJE E PËRDORUESVE TË TIK</option><option value="28">MEKANIKË</option><option value="32">NDËRTIM</option><option value="31">PËRPUNIM DRURI</option><option value="50">PETER MAHRINGER TEKNOLOGJI INFORMACIONI</option><option value="20">Psikologji</option><option value="19">Qytetari</option><option value="43">RRJETE TË DHËNASH</option><option value="41">SHËRBIME BANKARE</option><option value="27">SHËRBIME MJETESH TRANSPORTI</option><option value="36">SHËRBIME SOCIALE DHE SHËNDETSORE</option><option value="46">SILVIKULTURË</option><option value="22">Sociologji</option><option value="55">Spanjisht</option><option value="62">Spanjisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="17">Teknologji bërthamë</option><option value="18">Teknologji e thelluar</option><option value="34">TEKNOLOGJI USHQIMORE</option><option value="33">TEKSTIL-KONFEKSIONE</option><option value="57">Turqisht</option><option value="64">Turqisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="37">VETERINARI</option>            </select>
                        <div class="controls"><input name="F1" id="F1" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota e provimit me zgjedhje 1"></div>
                       </div>
                      </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                          <label class="control-label col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" for="Z2">Field6:</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                      <div class="row">
                       <div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between; flex-wrap:wrap;">
                        <select name="Z2" class="span2 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 form-control1" id="Z2">
                          <option value="0">Zgjidh Lëndën</option>
                          <option value="0" disabled="">---------------------------------------------------------</option>
                          <option value="42">ADMINSITRIM BIZNESI </option><option value="51">Anglisht</option><option value="58">Anglisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="9">Biologji bërthamë</option><option value="10">Biologji e thelluar</option><option value="35">BUJQËSI</option><option value="15">Ekonomi bërthamë</option><option value="16">Ekonomi e thelluar</option><option value="45">ELEKTRONIK NË TEKNOLOGJINË E AUTOMATIZIMIT </option><option value="30">ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="29">ELEKTROTEKNIKË</option><option value="21">Filozofi</option><option value="7">Fizikë bërthamë</option><option value="8">Fizikë e thelluar</option><option value="53">Frëngjisht</option><option value="60">Frengjisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="38">GJEODEZI</option><option value="13">Gjeografi bërthamë</option><option value="14">Gjeografi e thelluar</option><option value="54">Gjermanisht</option><option value="61">Gjermanisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="56">Greqisht</option><option value="63">Greqisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="49">HARRY FULTZ, AUTOMEKANIK</option><option value="47">HARRY FULTZ, BIZNES</option><option value="48">HARRY FULTZ, ELEKTRONIKË</option><option value="24">Histori arti</option><option value="25">Histori baleti</option><option value="11">Histori bërthamë</option><option value="12">Histori e thelluar</option><option value="23">Histori muzike</option><option value="26">HOTELERI-TURIZËM</option><option value="39">INSTALUES I SISTEMEVE TERMOHIDRAULIKE </option><option value="52">Italisht</option><option value="59">Italisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="5">Kimi bërthamë</option><option value="6">Kimi e thelluar</option><option value="3">Letërsi e thelluar</option><option value="40">LLOGARI</option><option value="4">Matematikë e thelluar</option><option value="44">MBËSHTETJE E PËRDORUESVE TË TIK</option><option value="28">MEKANIKË</option><option value="32">NDËRTIM</option><option value="31">PËRPUNIM DRURI</option><option value="50">PETER MAHRINGER TEKNOLOGJI INFORMACIONI</option><option value="20">Psikologji</option><option value="19">Qytetari</option><option value="43">RRJETE TË DHËNASH</option><option value="41">SHËRBIME BANKARE</option><option value="27">SHËRBIME MJETESH TRANSPORTI</option><option value="36">SHËRBIME SOCIALE DHE SHËNDETSORE</option><option value="46">SILVIKULTURË</option><option value="22">Sociologji</option><option value="55">Spanjisht</option><option value="62">Spanjisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="17">Teknologji bërthamë</option><option value="18">Teknologji e thelluar</option><option value="34">TEKNOLOGJI USHQIMORE</option><option value="33">TEKSTIL-KONFEKSIONE</option><option value="57">Turqisht</option><option value="64">Turqisht, Gjuhë e huaj e dytë</option><option value="37">VETERINARI</option>            </select>
                        <div class="controls"><input name="F2" id="F2" type="text" class="span1 form-control1" value="5.0" title="Nota e provimit me zgjedhje 2"></div>
                       </div>
                      </div>


                    </div>
```

Here is the formula:

```
{[26 x Field1 + 20 x Field2 + Field3 + Field4)] x 1.4 + 17 x (Field5 x 1.3 + Field6 x 1.2)} x 5
```

I found something here on stackoverflow but I could not modified it, I will show you that code maybe it can help:

```
Qty1 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty2 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty2"/><br>
Qty3 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty3"/><br>
Qty4 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty4"/><br>
Qty5 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty5"/><br>
Qty6 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty6"/><br>
Qty7 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty7"/><br>
Qty8 : <input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" name="qty" id="qty8"/><br>
<br><br>
Total : <input type="text" name="total" id="total"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">
function findTotal(){
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
            tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
    document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
}

    </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: Use the id of each `Field` input to get that value and include it in the formula. What you *"found"* is not relevant to your situation. Please note that this isn't a code writing or code conversion service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get input field value for each of the field.

field1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('M').value); will get the value for the first field.

Get the total value as per your formula.
var total= 5*((26 * field1 + 20 * field2 + field3 + field4) * 1.4 + 17 * (field5 * 1.3 + field6 * 1.2));

[See the JSBin for the modified code](http://jsbin.com/gigiwo/edit?html,js,console,output).

```
function findTotal(){
var field1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('M').value);
var field2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('D1').value);
var field3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('D2').value);
var field4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('D3').value);
var field5 = parseInt(document.getElementById('F1').value);
var field6 = parseInt(document.getElementById('F2').value);

var total= 5*((26 * field1 + 20 * field2 + field3 + field4) * 1.4 + 17 * (field5 * 1.3 + field6 * 1.2));


document.getElementById('total').value = total;}
```

Answer (score 0):

what exactly r u trying to achieve?
Calculate the result of the formula based on the input fields and display it to the user? Should this happen on click, on submit, on blur?

I guess this is what u r after ...
working [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/vizoxinalo/edit?html,css,js,output) (forumla values not tested)

to simplify your code,

html:

```
<input id='field-1' type='number' placeholder="field-1" />
<input id='field-2' type='number' placeholder="field-2" />
<input id='field-3' type='number' placeholder="field-3" />
<input id='field-4' type='number' placeholder="field-4" />
<input id='field-5' type='number' placeholder="field-5" />
<input id='field-6' type='number' placeholder="field-6" />
<button onClick=onClick()>Calculate</button>
```

js:

```
function onClick () {
  const Field1 = Number(document.getElementById('field-1').value)
  const Field2 = Number(document.getElementById('field-2').value)
  const Field3 = Number(document.getElementById('field-3').value)
  const Field4 = Number(document.getElementById('field-4').value)
  const Field5 = Number(document.getElementById('field-5').value)
  const Field6 = Number(document.getElementById('field-6').value)
  const res = ((26 * Field1 + 20 * Field2 + Field3 + Field4) * 1.4 + 17 * (Field5 * 1.3 + Field6 * 1.2)) * 5
  alert('res is ' + res)
}
```